# How can I avoid null pointer access warning when the check is inside a method?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I dispose of the following method :

```
boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
  return s == null || s.length() == 0;
}
```

Trouble is, it isn't compatible with `@Nullable`. For istance, in the following code, a warning is displayed when it shouldn't.

```
void test(@Nullable String s) {
  if (!isNullOrEmpty(s)) {
    s.length(); // warning : o may be null
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this warning go away while conserving `isNullOrEmpty` and `Nullable` ?

Comment: What is the IDE/framework that you use to produce this warning? IntelliJ for example does not produce a warning thanks to the method contract of `Objects.isNull`: `!null->false;null->true`.

Comment: Based on your comment on @Remi's answer, I wonder whether you haven't gone just a bit too far trying to make this a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example. (I.e. perhaps it's just a bit less than Minimal?) I'm left wondering whether the problem exists inside your `isNullOrEmpty(List)` method, or in the use of its returned boolean value.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom it's eclipse yes, but I guess you're write, l'll edit my question

Comment: What's the advantage of `isNullOrEmpty(s)` over `s==null||s.isEmpty()`? To a Java developer the latter should read as "is null or is empty"...

Comment: Guava's Precondition.checkNotNull if you want to throw an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you refactored a bit to use `Optional` you'd be better off.

```
@NonNull Optional<String> optNullOrEmpty(@Nullable String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
    return Optional.empty();
  else
    return Optional.of(s);
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
void test(@Nullable String s) {
  @NonNull Optional<String> os = optNullOrEmpty(s);
  if (os.isPresent()) {
    @NonNull String s1 = os.get();
    s1.length(); // No warning :-)
  }
}
```

Comment: I like it ! The only trouble I see is the refactoring cost (`isNullOrEmpty` is called a lot).

Comment: @fxm, yeah, that's the downside. OTOH, you kind of incurred the technical debt as soon as you turned on the @Nullable annotation. At this point you have to touch all of those invocations somehow. And based solely on my own subjective experience, it seems like `Optional` and @Nullable go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason for you not to use if (o != null) ?

The purpose of Objects.isNull is to be used as a predicate : 
.filter(Objects::isNull)

This warning might be a bug though. You can annotate your method with @SuppressWarnings if you really want it to go away

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I'm aware of these two solutions, but they're not what I'm looking for : the SuppressWarnings is way too brutal for "real code" and the `!= null` is what I wish to avoid

Comment: I'm curious as why you wish to avoid using != null, it litteraly does the same thing as !Objects.isNull (the method just does a "return object == null;")

Comment: I have custom functions performing `isNullOrEmpty` tests (on List, for instance). These functions have the same problem than the one I describe with `isNull`.